# How list child after parent in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have data in mysql table like this

```
id ||  act  || parent || level
1  ||   13  ||  0     ||  1
2  ||   13  ||  0     ||  1 
3  ||   13  ||  1     ||  2
4  ||   13  ||  2     ||  2
5  ||   13  ||  1     ||  2
```

How to query in mysql, if i want the result like this :

```
id ||  act  || parent || level
1  ||   13  ||  0     ||  1
3  ||   13  ||  1     ||  2 
5  ||   13  ||  1     ||  2
2  ||   13  ||  0     ||  1
4  ||   13  ||  2     ||  2
```

Thank's before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here would be to determine a custom sorting parameter. It `parent` value is 0, we can simply use that row's `id` value; else the `parent` value. This is because the `parent` value for other levels is same the row `id` for the parent.

We will also use multiple level `Order By`, with second level ordering done using `id`.

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  act, 
  parent, 
  level, 
  (CASE WHEN parent = 0 THEN id ELSE parent END) AS custom_sort_parameter 
FROM 
  your_table_name 
ORDER BY custom_sort_parameter, id
```

I have done calculation of `custom_sort_parameter` in the `Select` clause, for code readability and ease to understand. But you can shift it to `Order By` clause instead (to avoid getting one more unnecessary column). It is exhibited in the Demo below.

---

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
Create table your_table_name 
(id int, act int, parent int, level int);

Insert into your_table_name 
VALUES (1,13,0,1), 
       (2,13,0,1), 
       (3,13,1,2), 
       (4,13,2,2), 
       (5,13,1,2);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  act, 
  parent, 
  level
FROM 
  your_table_name 
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN parent = 0 THEN id 
    ELSE parent 
  END 
  , id;

| id  | act | parent | level |
| --- | --- | ------ | ----- |
| 1   | 13  | 0      | 1     |
| 3   | 13  | 1      | 2     |
| 5   | 13  | 1      | 2     |
| 2   | 13  | 0      | 1     |
| 4   | 13  | 2      | 2     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cga9XbkjWU6YWMztVabEkv/0)

Comment: @user3562918 happy to help :)